# Perform numerical operation in subset of IDs and return the results in the same data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a large dataset consisting of longitudinal measurements in various subjects (IDs) and some variables lets say:

```
test.df <- data.frame(id=c(rep("A", 50),rep("B", 50)), x1=rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100))
```

I want to perform some numerical operation on all records of each ID and return the results in the same dataset.

Right now what I am doing is:

```
test.df <- data.frame(id=c(rep("A", 50),rep("B", 50)), x1=rnorm(50), x2=rnorm(50))

test.df$mean.of.x1<-NA
test.df$mean.of.x2<-NA

for(i in unique(test.df$id)){
  test.df$mean.of.x1[test.df$id==i]<-mean(test.df$x1[test.df$id==i])
  test.df$mean.of.x2[test.df$id==i]<-mean(test.df$x2[test.df$id==i])
}
```

The example is very simplistic (and perhaps silly), but it shows what I need (in my original problem there are several function to be run for each ID not just `mean`). Is there a more efficient way to do this? Can any `*apply` function help?

Comment: Did you mean to create an example test like:   test.df <- data.frame(id=c(rep("A", 50),rep("B", 50)), x1=rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100)).  The way you currently has it just assigns the same values to both groups, so their means will all be the same

Comment: yes. thanks for that. I corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transform(test.df, mean.of.x1 = ave(x1, id, FUN=mean), 
                   mean.of.x2 = ave(x2, id, FUN=mean))
```

Comment: What a beautiful one liner. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

A combination of aggregate and merge will do the trick.

```
results = aggregate(x=test.df, list(test.df$id), mean)
test.df.updated = merge(test.df, results, by.x = 1, by.y=1)
```